# How to make SVG scale only on X axis?

Tags: svg, responsive

I have the following SVG graphic that is currently scaling when the window is resized, but the aspect ratio is maintained. How could I get this to only scale on the X axis, and keep the Y at 80px?

```
<svg width="100%" viewBox="0 0 300 80">
  <rect x="0" y="0" fill="yellow" height="80" width="100"/>
  <rect x="100" y="0" fill="blue" height="80" width="100"/>
  <rect x="200" y="0" fill="red" height="80" width="100"/>
</svg>
```

Thank you,

Answer (score 4):

You have a couple of options. First, you could simply specify the height of the graphic, e.g. using CSS.

```
svg {
    height: 80px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

If that's not the effect you want, you can get more sophisticated with the [`preserveAspectRatio`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/preserveAspectRatio) attribute. It's hard to say what value would work for you since it's not completely clear what you want (assuming the CSS approach above doesn't do it), but maybe something like:

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 300 80" preserveAspectRatio="none">
```

Check out the reference link for more details.

Comment: Your first approach will not work. OP should use the second approach (`preserveAspectRatio`).